# Fazer busca na database com dados encriptados

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, criptografia

Possuo uma *database* onde os dados inseridos são encriptados através de uma função escrita em PHP, essa função encripta e desencripta. Preciso fazer busca nessa tabela.

Por exemplo, eu busco por "BRASIL", mas na tabela o "BRASIL" está encriptado como: `cdlddzfqm3b3szyxvvk2u3n6lzb1ut09`

Uso PHP e MySQL, e para fazer as buscas uso `LIKE % %`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não foram dados muitos detalhes mas pela forma descrita acredito que seja só criptografar o que você deseja procurar, aí a comparação será feita do dado criptografado com outro dado **igualmente** criptografado.

```
$query = "select * from tabela where campo = " . crypt("BRASIL");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/CryptQuery.php).

Isto pode não funcionar dependendo de alguns fatores como a a forma como é feita a criptografia, configuração do banco de dados para comparação (*collation*), etc. Mas acredito que você está usando uma forma simples e esta forma funcionará.

Com `LIKE` em condições normais não é possível, pelo menos desconheço uma forma. Talvez seja possível com algum módulo adicional ao MySQL mas desconheço algum que faça isto. Na verdade não sei se é uma boa ideia fazer isto.

Talvez seja possível criar uma função para o MySQL (possivelmente em C) que possa ser usado no lugar do ou com o `LIKE` para fazer esta busca. nem vou especular muito em cima disto porque não parece ser a melhor das ideias.

Uma possível solução horrorosa seria pegar todos os dados criptografados, descriptografar no PHP e fazer a seleção. É mais fácil de fazer que a solução anterior mas pavorosa para usar.

Achei [essa solução no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7613456/221800) para criptografia *builtin* do MySQL. Não saberia dizer todas as limitações exceto a performance já citada lá.

```
select * from tabela where aes_decrypt(campo, salt) like '%BRASIL%'
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Crypt.sql).

Obviamente isto só funcionado se o dado está gravado da mesma forma.

Veja [outras funções de criptografia *builtin*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) do MySQL.

Comment: Poise, porem preciso usar o LIKE e nao funcionaria este metodo.

Comment: Só que você não colocou isto na pergunta.

Comment: Perdao, eu omiti detalhes, ja arrumei. Irei ler sua resposta.

Comment: Dessa forma só seria possivel com esse tipo de encriptaçao correto?

Comment: Poderia ser com qualquer tipo de criptografia *builtin*.

Comment: Eu uso uma funçao em php que encrypta com base64 e chaves

Comment: Como falei, aí complicaria muito, teria que usar soluções extramente complexas. Fora que Base64 não criptografa nada.

Comment: Veja, AES-256-CBC é o metodo que a funçao utiliza

Comment: Mas não é a função *builtin* do MySQL. Pelo menos de acordo com o que você disse.

Comment: Oi, fiz minhas adaptações e cheguei a uma duvida, estou inserindo agora usando a funçao AES do mysql, e em seguida usando o TO_BASE64 para "encapar" o código, tentei usar agora `select * from tabela where FROM_BASE64(aes_decrypt(campo, salt)) like '%BRASIL%'` porém nao funciona, por que?

Comment: Não sei dizer, não há informações suficientes http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Note que este já um problema diferente do que você postou originalmente na pergunta.